# Nested Create Type in Stored Procedure Declaration T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am writing a SQL Stored Proc which takes in a single table valued parameter. Is it possible for me to create the table type in the parameter definition, for example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE example (
  @param (CREATE TYPE tableparameter ( column1 int, colunn2 varchar.... )) READONLY
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.
Databases will want the type to already exist before it can be specified as a parameter type, otherwise the database has no way to know if the data it is receiving is valid or not.